# angularjs ng-show delay in hidden div with same model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My code is given below:

```
<button class="btn-border-blue" ng-show="!hasCouponCode" ng-click="hasCouponCode = true;">Cupom</button>
<div class="form-inline-cupom" ng-show="hasCouponCode">
    <input type="text" ng-model="couponCode" placeholder="Código do cupom">
    <button class="btn-green" ng-click="addCoupon()">Add cupom</button>
</div>
```

When I click on the button, it changes the model value "hasCouponCode", hides the button and shows the `div` element, but there is delay and visual is bad.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Visual is bad, as in?

Comment: Remove ngAnimate from your app if you inject it

Comment: Is bad, because first show the div and only after 1 or 2 seconds that the button is hidden

Answer (score 0):

I created this snippet and it runs pretty quickly. I think you might have a server callback in the addCoupon() method that's slowing it down. You should improve the performance of the server side code. If you can't, it'd be nice to add a loading screen to the view so the user knows something is working while waiting. I hope it helped.

```js
(function(angular) {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  var Maincontroller = function($scope) {
    $scope.addCoupon = function() {
      $scope.mycoupon = $scope.couponCode;
    }
  };

  app.controller("maincontroller", ["$scope", Maincontroller]);
}(angular));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="maincontroller">
    <button class="btn-border-blue" ng-show="!hasCouponCode" ng-click="hasCouponCode = true;">Cupom</button>
    <div class="form-inline-cupom" ng-show="hasCouponCode">
      <input type="text" ng-model="couponCode" placeholder="Código do cupom">
      <button class="btn-green" ng-click="addCoupon()">Add cupom</button>

    </div>
    <p>{{mycoupon}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by surrounding your button with an external div, and then using the ng-show in that div. Like this :

```
<div ng-show="!hasCouponCode">
<button class="btn-border-blue" ng-click="hasCouponCode = true;">Cupom</button>
</div>
```

Like this, you can apply it to rest of your code too.